# Convert Oracle query to Access

Tags: oracle, oracle10g, ms-access-2010

```
SELECT mrno,createddate FROM 
(SELECT HMISAKHSP.mrrh_antenatalcare.*, ROW_NUMBER() OVER 
(PARTITION BY mrno ORDER BY createddate DESC) AS RN FROM 
HMISAKHSP.mrrh_antenatalcare) 
WHERE RN = 1  and deliverybooked = 'B' ORDER BY mrno
```

This is my oracle query which working fine but When I tried to run this query on Access I got error `Syntax error Missing Operator`.

Comment: Were you able to pinpoint the approximate location of the error ? Maybe by trying to remove various clauses from your query

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately every database management system has its own **dialect** of SQL. There are changes from version to version of one DBMS as well.

So basic SQL statements like

```
select * from mytable
```

are widely supported, but specialities like **window functions**

```
select row_number() over (...) from mytable
```

are not.

Additional you want to use **MSAccess** which is IMHO far away from the SQL possibilities of Oracle, SQLServer, PostgreSQL, MySQL and so on.

You should definitly using one of these *large* DBMS.

I don't think MSAcess has support for **window functions**.